# Get DAG Email from another DAG in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to get the email mentioned in this DAG's default args using another DAG in the airflow. How can I do that? Please help, I am new to airflow!

```
from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG

def first_function(**context):
    print("hello")

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['example@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(
    'main',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Sample DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    start_date=datetime(2022,6,10),
    catchup=False
) as dag:
    first_function = PythonOperator(
        task_id="first_function",
        python_callable=first_function,
    )
first_function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom module](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html) in Airflow to share config options/Operators/or any arbitrary Python code across DAGs.

Typically you would create a directory in your DAGs directory (which by default is `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags`.

To share `default_args` between DAGs, you could create the following layout:

- Create `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/custom/__init__.py`
- Create `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/custom/shared_config.py`
- Create `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/.airflowignore`
- Add the directory name `custom` to the first line of `.airflowignore`.
- Cut and paste your `default_args` dictionary from your DAG into `{AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags/custom/shared_config.py`

You can see this layout suggested in the Airflow documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/modules_management.html#typical-structure-of-packages).

The `.airflowignore` tells the scheduler to skip the `custom` directory when it parses your DAGs (which by default happens every 30s) - because the `custom` directory contains Python, but never any DAGs, the scheduler should skip these files to avoid adding unnecessary load to the scheduler. This is explained in the documentation link above.

You need to add an `__init__.py` to the custom directory - airflow requires it even though when writing in Python3 you don't need it because of implicit namespaces (again this is explained in the same link above).

From your dag you can then import as needed:

```py
from custom.shared_config import default_args
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!
But what if the default_args are dynamic, as in different in all DAGs. Let's say I want to schedule a DAG in airflow that collects the owner's name and email from all other scheduled DAGs and sends them emails on completion/failure of their DAG runs. How can I do that?

Comment: If they're dynamic could you not use `on_failure_callback` and `on_success_callback` in the DAG (you can see them in the [DAG options](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG)? If you wanted to export the `default_args` you could have a task in each DAG that takes the `default_args` and sets a Variable/XCom, which another DAG could read.